# How To Do This in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var sunny=[1,2,3];
var bunny=[4,5,6];
var name=prompt("Enter Name");

for(var i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    document.write(name[i]);
}
//If User input Sunny then array elements of sunny will be printed.
```

Comment: And what if the user enters neither "sunny" nor "bunny"?

Comment: Not one of the answers here have a solution. Probably because low quality questions attracts low quality answers (And the user selects the one one `eval` how surprising)

Comment: Because I want to implement this code on https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bxq5hYau2MywOHd0elM3dFZzQlk  this and this helps me to do the thing perfectly.and for your kind information this is my first question on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

U can achieve this by using 'eval'.

See the update code.

```
var sunny=[1,2,3];
var bunny=[4,5,6];
var name=prompt("Enter Name");

for(var i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    document.write(eval(name)[i]);
}
```

Comment: eval is evil...

Comment: Problem Solved Because of You.Thanks

Comment: Awesome! Would you mind marking this as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use object for `users` and write your users in it, **example:**

```js
var users = {
    sunny: [1,2,3],
    bunny: [4,5,6]
}
var name = prompt("Enter Name");
console.log(users[name]);

//If User input Sunny then array elements of sunny will be printed.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to use an object:

```
const names = {
  sunny:[1,2,3],
  bunny:[4,5,6],
};

const name=prompt("Enter Name");

for(var i=0;i<3;i++)
{
  document.write(names[name][i]);
}
```

There is *not clean way* to get a variable if you have its name as string. However its easy to access an objects properties with a string with the `[]` syntax.

Comment: *"Also notice that javascript has no equivalent of prompt"* - Um...what about the [`window.prompt()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt), which can be called as `prompt()` without the `window.` part.

Answer (score -3):

You can use a switch-statement (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp) like

```
var a;
switch(name) {
  case "sunny":
    a = sunny;
    break;
  case "bunny":
    a = bunny;
    break;
}

for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  document.write(a[i]);
}
```

Comment: Not Working <script>
var sunny=[1,2,3]
var bunny=[4,5,6]
var a;
switch(name) {
  case "sunny":
    a = sunny;
    break;
  case "bunny":
    a = bunny;
    break;
}

for(var i = 0;i<3; i++) {
  document.write(a[i]);
}
</script>

Comment: Please provide an error message.

Comment: Problem Solved Using Eval.

Comment: You'd also need to have a default case to avoid errors if they entered an unknown string.